# Unity C# compile c# static class script from file

Tags: unity-game-engine

for my game I have a class which takes care of some of the functions activated by items and mission completions etc.. It's a simple static class that has a list of Actions, nothing fancy, it doesn't even inherit from Mono. The question : I want people to theoretically add functions on a web page dynamically...  So first I need to figure out how to load and compile a C# class from at least a text file.

So, how do I? I tried using someone in the CSharp class, but unity said it's not recognized.

And BTW I need to be able to access the classes variables in other scripts, like Class.functions0 for example.

Comment: Hmm, very interesting question, have you read somewhere that this is possible. My personal opinion is this should not be possible since the compiler is not within the build product. Meaning you shouldn't be able to compile after you've built an app. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: According to [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/future-plans-for-the-mono-runtime-upgrade.464327/page-4#post-3521585), Roslyn (that's what the CSharp namespace is) requires a beta release at this time, and I'm not entirely sure if it supports runtime or just the editor, but you are at least on the right path.

Comment: add `Microsoft.CSharp` and `System.CodeDom.Compiler` dlls to `\Assets\Plugins` to use them as external plugins, read this: https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/715891/Compiling-Csharp-Code-at-Runtime

Comment: @JinJi does it work for exporting to WEbGL and android/iphone?

Comment: to add any .net assembly to your unity project, you have to copy it to your `Assets/Libraries` folder in your unity editor. then go to: `edit / project settings / player / other settings / optimization / api compatibility level` and set it to: .NET 2.0

Comment: @JinJi I want to set mine to .NET 4x does that work too?